# import select2 scss from node_modules

Tags: javascript, css, npm, gulp

I am trying to import select2 scss from node_modules.

I have installed select2 by command\

`npm install select2` and got `select2` folder in node_modules folder

How can I import css for select2 in app.scss file.

I am using gulp.

Thanks

Comment: I created a full answer based on the same question about `select2`. You can find it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108539/3452348)

Answer (score 2):

`@import "node_modules/select2/css";`

You can add this at the top of the SCSS file.

Comment: If that doesn't work straight away you can have a look at this css importer plugin for sass. https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer

Comment: Just `@import "select2";` is sufficient, at the time of writing this comment