# How to use npm installed package in laravel application?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, jquery-select2

I want to use **select2** package in my laravel 5 application.

I installed it using `npm install select2` and also ran `npm run dev`. It appears in my **node_modules** folder.

But how do I actually refer to the files - js and scss of **select2** package in my `app.blade.php` ?

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. Have you searched for a solution?

Answer (score 10):

Run `npm run watch` , because keeps track of all changes in `.js`.

In app.js add

```
require('select2/dist/js/select2');
```

In app.blade.php example:

```
<div>            
   <select class="js-select2 css-select2-50">
                    <option>1</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, while `npm run watch`, just saving the your update on `app.js` will automatically re-compile app.js to add the module.

Comment: Man! Thank you for this solution. I've been at this for hours. YouTube, Google no one is showing instructions step by step. Thanks again!

Comment: This thread is old, but more detail would greatly help. I installed tablesorter via npm and, while I do see it in my `node_modules` folder and have added `require('tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.min.js');` to the app.js file, I can't understand how I'm supposed to import the script file into my HTML.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest an answer to this thread because it isn't marked as resolved and despite the answer given it didn't allow me to resolve the issue as of the time of reading this.

---

### Resources

- [select2.org](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/select2)

---

I have since found a functional solution of which here are the details in relation to the question of the OP. Verified and working with **Laravel 8**

1. Install package via npm

   ```
   npm install select2
   ```
2. Edit **`/resources/js/app.js`** to import javascript from package

   ```
   require('./bootstrap');

   /* ... */
   require('select2');  // Add this
   /* ... */

   Alpine.start();
   ```
3. Edit **`/resources/css/app.css`** to import styles from package

   ```
   /* ... */
   @import 'select2'; // Add this
   ```
4. Edit **`/resources/js/bootstrap.js`** to enable the use of `.select2();`

   ```
   window._ = require('lodash');
   /* ... */
   window.select2 = require('select2'); // Add this
   ```
5. Run NPM

   ```
   npm run dev
   npm run watch
   ```
6. NPM result in my case

> Laravel Mix v6.0.39
> ✔ Compiled Successfully in 2982ms
>
> √ Mix: Compiled successfully in 3.05s
> webpack compiled successfully

---

### Testing

According to [configuration documentation](https://select2.org/configuration)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control js-example-basic-single">
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select2 testing purpose'
    });

  });
</script>
```

**Render**

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.