# ReferenceError: vis is not defined

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I installed vis.js through npm `npm install vis-network`

and already require it in my `app.js`

```
try {
    require('vis-network');
} catch (e) { }
```

and recompiled it in laravel mix

```
npm run dev
```

but whenever I instantiate a vis instance I always get `vis is not define` error on console..

```
<script>
let nodes = new vis.DataSet(_nodes),
    edges = new vis.DataSet(_connections);

...
let network = new vis.Network(container, { nodes: nodes, edges: edges }, _options);
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you are requiring with `const vis =  require('vis-network');`

Comment: hm, no. I only require it with `require('vis-network')`

Comment: try with above line in the file you use vis

Comment: hm, now it give me `require is not defined`

Comment: Could you include the part of code where you require `vis`? (With a bit more context)

Comment: @FZs I just wrapped it in a try catch block on my app.js..I'm using laravel framework btw

Comment: @FZs then on my blade template I use the vis with the last script on my question

Comment: **You didn't define the `vis` variable! Define it as @AbishekKumar has mentioned, and to put it into the correct scope, move it out of the `try` block.** It wouldn't make sense to have it in the `try`, as if the `require` would have failed, then the code that uses it would throw.

Comment: I changed it to `window.vis =  require('vis-network');` and the error changed to `vis.DataSet is not a constructor`

Comment: ah I think it is now resolved...vis.DataSet might be another issue I need to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it to the window object, to escape the node encapsulating context.

```
try {
    window.vis = require('vis-network/standalone');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: `require` is not defined in a browser.

Comment: `vis.DataSet is not a constructor` I receive this after doing that

Comment: This fixed it. Looks like I need to require the `require('vis-network/standalone')` instead of vis-network only to resolve the `vis.DataSet is not a constructor` error

Comment: @DarthVader thanks,  I've edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need too bundle your application ton convert commonJS modules to browser supported code.

See this question: [How to use npm installed package in laravel application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402858/how-to-use-npm-installed-package-in-laravel-application)

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I did..of course I ran `npm run dev` after changing my app.js to recompile it