# convert .obj to .glb using npm+laravel

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, npm

I am stopped at one point for 2 days and not able to fix.

Can anyone please help me through this?

Question: How can I convert .obj file o .glb?

I used [obj2gltf](https://github.com/CesiumGS/obj2gltf) package of npm and search to implement it with Laravel but nothing helped. so now I am confused that does I am doing anything wrong?

Also I tried [this article](https://www.laravelcode.com/post/data-scraping-with-node-js-and-display-in-laravel) to use the node with PHP/Laravel and [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402858/how-to-use-npm-installed-package-in-laravel-application) from stack overflow.

Can anyone please help me through this?

Thank you in the advance guys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no solution in pure PHP. But you may create a JS script that converts your files using `obj2gltf` lib and then execute the script from the PHP in some kind of like that:

```php
//php

$converter = '/path/to/your/script.js';
$objFilePath = '/path/to/your/3d.obj';

$glbFilePath = trim(shell_exec("node $converter $objFilePath"));
```

And let's say, your JS is converting your 3D object and then returning a path to the converted file:

```js
// script.js

const obj2gltf = require("obj2gltf");
const fs = require("fs");

obj2gltf(process.argv[2])
    .then(function (gltf) {
        const data = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(gltf));
        fs.writeFileSync("result.gltf", data);

        console.log(process.cwd() + "/result.gltf");
    });
```

Comment: I can not get your point properly. I can do it with JS no problem. But in js file

const obj2gltf = require("obj2gltf");

Which file i want to put need to use any CDN?

Comment: Not CDN, script should run on the same server where your PHP code is