# Problems using SweetAlert2 in a blade view - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have had many problems to integrate sweetalert 2 in Laravel. I have tried it in several ways and they all give me a different error.

First, I need to install it by NPM and in a blade view. I install it normal, but when I place:

```
<script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

This pops up:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/sweetalert2.all.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I understand that localhost:8000 is the server I have, but I don't know how to fix that problem.

And if I try to put this:

```
const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
```

It appears require is not defined

What could I do to solve any of the problems and use sweetalert2 in a blade view in Laravel? thanks

Comment: Where did you put the `require` call?

Comment: @ceejayoz In the head of the HTML view

Comment: Is your sweetalert2.all.min.js in  /public/js ?

Comment: have you double check the path of your sweetalert2.all.min.js?

Comment: @xun No, esta en la vista blade. Iria en public/js?

Comment: This may be helpful  [Use Npm installed package in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108539)

Comment: @JoseLopez `require` is intended for use with a JavaScript preprocessor like Mix or Vite. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your `sweetalert2.all.min.js` into `\public\vendor` folder. Then in view xxx.blade.php link it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{'/vendor/sweetalert2.all.min.js'}}"></script>
```

On my installed Laravel 10x, in this way I've connected other js scripts.